# I'd like to set the automatic wrapping of Text Area with CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to create a Text Area to copy and enter 7 digit serial numbers from Excel.

The problem is that while Excel recommends copying and entering numbers, there will be users who enter serial numbers by hand. 
Therefore, even if the user enters the serial number by hand, I would like to set the text area to wrap every seven characters so that User can verify that the serial number entered is 7 digits.

Of course i can implement this with javascript, but can i limit the length of the line with just a simple setup of CSS?

I tried it with the code bellow, but it didn't work...

```
<textarea
              rows="7"
              cols="7"  
              wrap="hard"> 
        Some serial number on here.
</textarea>
```

If anyone have a way, I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rows` and `cols` attributes specify the `visible` width. What you require is something that will force the text to wrap after 7 characters. The only way to do this in CSS for a textarea is to set a fixed width equal to the length of 7 characters.

```
textarea{
    resize: none;
    width: 7em;
}
```

Instead of using `px` you can set a fixed width of `7em`.
Here `1em` is equal to  the current font size so `7em` will be 7 characters wide. The `row` attribute in the `textarea` will then force the text to wrap if an additional character is entered.

If `7em` does not work, it is possible that there is additional `padding` and `line-height` too needs to be taken in to account as well. You'll have to adjust the width accordingly.

You should also set the `resize: none;` style to prevent users from resizing the textarea.